# Create a new object by modifying an existing object

Tags: python, object, copy

I have created the following class:

```
class ball:
    def __init__(self,d=0,weight=0):
        self.d = d
        self.weight = weight
```

Then we have a global function that returns a ball with a modified weight, which is defined as follows:

```
def modifyWeight(ball, weight):
    ball.weight = weight
    return ball
```

And finally, the main function, which creates a lists of balls given a list of weights:

```
def createBallList(ball, weights):
    ballList = []
    for weight in weights:
        modifyWeight(ball,weight)
        ballList.append(ball)

    return ballList
```

Well, that being explained, if `weights = [20,25,15]` I expected that:

```
ball = ball(2)
ballList = creatBallList(ball,weights)

ballList[0].weight = 20
ballList[1].weight = 25
ballList[2].weight = 15
```

but it turns out being:

```
ballList[0].weight = 15
ballList[1].weight = 15
ballList[2].weight = 15
```

Have been trying couple things, but nothing apparently works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `ball.weight = weight`, you don't create a new ball.  You change the weight of the existing ball.  When you do `ballList.append(ball)`, you are appending the same ball over and over again to the list.  The list contains the same ball three times.

If you want to create a new ball on each trip through the loop, create a new ball on each trip through the loop:

```
def createBallList(weights):
    ballList = []
    for weight in weights:
        newBall = ball(weight=weight)
        ballList.append(newBall)

    return ballList
```

Note that you don't need to pass a `ball` to `createBallList`.  If it'all it's doing is creating new balls, and not making use of the original ball, it doesn't really need the original ball at all.

I'm not sure what the role of `d` is in your `ball` class, or why you set it to 2, so I've omitted that part of it here.  You could do `ball(d=2, weight=weight)` to create new balls with `d` set to 2.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a copy of the object, you are just repeatedly adding the same object to the list so when you set the weight you are setting it for the same object, use [copy.deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) to actually create a new object.

```
from copy import deepcopy 
cp_b = deepcopy(ball) # new copy of the ball object
modifyWeight(cp_b,weight)
```